FN20 key firing twice with different codes (FN20 & XF86AudioMicMute)
I'm on Arch Linux with Hyprland (I don't think its relevant but still). I just did a clean install and tried to setup the Mic Mute key like I had did while following this from the Manjaro Forums. But it seems that there is some issue that makes the mic mute fire twice, first as F20 and then as XF86AudioMicMute. This leads the the hyprland keybind toggling the Mic mute status and then reverting back on key release.
I ran
# libinput debug-events --show-keycodes

This the output on pressing the F20 (Mic Mute) Key:
-event3   KEYBOARD_KEY                +0.000s   KEY_F20 (190) pressed
 event3   KEYBOARD_KEY                +0.130s   KEY_F20 (190) released
-event18  KEYBOARD_KEY                +0.330s   KEY_MICMUTE (248) pressed
 event18  KEYBOARD_KEY                +0.330s   KEY_MICMUTE (248) released

This wasn't a problem in the previous arch install. Is there a way where I can disable the re-fire?
My Laptop is: HP Envy 14 - Eb0021TX.
TIA

Do those 4 lines appear together in the libinput output? It seems strange to have the second set 3ms later.

What input devices are event3 and event18 in this case? You have two different drivers reacting to the same event (e.g. maybe the firmware issues one "real" keypress from the keyboard device and then a slower ACPI event from some platform device).

@grawity Event 18 seems to be HP WMI hotkeys and 3 is the main keyboard. This wasn't a issue before. Is it possible windows changed something (i've a dual boot setup)? Thanks.
